# How can I stub same method multiple times with different query chain depending on their arguments and get different results?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, sinon

I'm trying to mock two variables made of mongoose queries. These are;
`const totalUser = User.find().countDocuments().exec()` and
`const lastWeekUser = User.find({ createdAt: { $lt: lastWeek }}).countDocuments()`.

In the test I use jest and sinon. The result I come up with;

```
         sinon
            .stub(User, 'find')
            .withArgs()
            .callsFake((): any => {
                return {
                    countDocuments: sinon.stub().callsFake(() => {
                        return {
                            exec: sinon.stub().returns(newUserCount),
                        }
                    }),
                }
            })
            .withArgs({
                createdAt: { $lt: lastWeek },
            })
            .callsFake((): any => {
                return {
                    countDocuments: sinon.stub().callsFake(() => {
                        return {
                            exec: sinon.stub().returns(mockedData.length),
                        }
                    }),
                }
            })
```

When I try to run the test I took the error of "Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.".
What should I do wrong? How can I correct this? Or is it impossible to use argument on a find query in a test?

Comment: Don't mock what you don't own. Mongoose has a complex API; push it behind a facade you do own and can easily mock, and/or test at an integration level. Otherwise even trivial refactors give failing tests that lie to you about whether your code actually works.

Comment: You mean what I should actually mock is totalUser in `const totalUser = User.find().countDocuments().exec()` ?  I guess to mock totalUser I need to take it inside a function. Do I have any chance to do it without changing the code?

Comment: For that, for example, you'd have something like `const totalCount = userRepository.count()`. The repository is yours, you can mock that without delving through chained property access and coupling too closely to the persistence details.